# Python: Subprocess works different to terminal. What I have to change?

Tags: python

I have to Python scripts: Tester1.py and Tester2.py.
Within Tester1 I want to start from time to time Tester2.py. I also want to pass Tester2.py some arguments. At the moment my code looks like this:

Tester1:

```
subprocess.call(['python3 Tester2.py testString'])
```

Tester2:

```
def start():
    message = sys.argv[1]
    print(message)

start()
```

Now my problem: If I run with my terminal Tester2 like 'python3 Tester2.py testString'my console prints out testString. But if I run Tester1 and Tester1 tries to start Tester2, I get an IndexError: "list index out of range".

How do I need to change my code to get everything working?

EDIT:
niemmi told me that I have to change my code to:

```
subprocess.call(['python3', 'Tester2.py', 'testString'])
```

but now I get a No such file or directory Error although both scripts are in the same directory. Someone knows why?

Comment: FYI, if you're using python 3.5 or higher, the documentation recommends to use the run() function of subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the arguments either as separate elements on a list or as a string:

```
subprocess.call(['python3', 'Tester2.py', 'testString'])
# or
subprocess.call('python3 Tester2.py testString')
```

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) has following description:

> *args* is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

Comment: Now I get a No such file or directory Error although both scripts are in the same directory?

Comment: Path is relative to the location where you run `Tester1.py` from. If you `cd` to the directory where the both scripts are located it should work. Other alternative is to have `Tester1` to define the full path.

Comment: so you mean
subprocess.call('cd path')
subprocess.call('python3 ...)
I have to call in my function?

Comment: @TomHere No, I was referring to command line if that's where you run the script from. Anyway if you define absolute path of `tester2.py` to `subprocess.call` it should work: `subprocess.call('python3 absolute/path/Tester2.py testString')`

Comment: And for the record, a subprocess which runs `cd` does not have any effect on its parent script or any other subprocess started by it, so doing that is completely pointless.

Comment: @niemmi I am to silly. I just forgot to change the name "Tester2.py" back to my real scripts name^^

Comment: @TomHere No worries, I'm happy the problem got solved